# Why digital certificate doesn't ask for password in Linux?

Tags: certificates

I have imported a personal digital certificate into a Linux Mint computer (OS is up to date, certificate is imported in Firefox and Chrome). I used a password in the process of importing, but after that, no password is needed. Why?
I wasn't asked for security level like on Windows. For example - on a Windows computer, I set a High-security level and after that I'm asked for a password when it is used. Any idea how to change this insecure behavior on Linux?

Comment: Have you set a master-password in Firefox?

Comment: Yes, I have master password in FF. But I can imagine that some malicious website/script can use my certificate without my knowledge. I was really surprised. Until some weeks ago, I use personal digital certificate only on my Windows computer.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, note that this is a behavior of the Windows key store (and some other key stores), not of certificates in general or anything like that. Firefox doesn't use the Windows key store even on Windows; you'd see the same behavior there. Linux doesn't have a platform key store, so every browser there either uses their own key store (such as Mozilla apps like Firefox) or a shared one of their choice. Chrome on Linux in particular uses NSS, the same library that Firefox uses, although I think it uses a different database (Chrome uses $HOME/.pki/nssdb, Firefox uses something under ~/.mozilla/firefox/{profile}/ apparently).

It's also only insecure if you let other people, who you don't trust, access your machine using your user account (or as the superuser). That is, to put it mildly, already an extremely bad idea. All your other browser secrets (such as session tokens in cookies or local storage, saved passwords and payment info, browser history, and so on) are also all stored either in plain text or reversibly encrypted using keys available to the user. Plus, of course, everything else in your user profile (documents, pictures/videos, non-browser apps and all their saved data, etc.). It could also be a risk if your machine was stolen and you don't have full volume encryption enabled.

Microsoft put a lot of effort into the cryptographic security module used for key storage on Windows, including the ability to store keys such that they can't be retrieved (only used for various operations, like signing, which is how TLS client certs work) and the ability to store the keys encrypted not just with a per-user (or per-machine) key but also with a key-specific password-derived key. It's mostly useful for legacy reasons, though; back in the days when there were non-NT-based Windows versions, or when NT could be installed on a FAT-based file system that doesn't support access controls, a computer that was used by multiple people had no way to prevent one user from accessing another user's data, so highly-sensitive data like private keys offered the option of requiring a password on every use. These days, just give every user their own non-admin account and you've achieved most of the same protection.

Linux does not, out of the box, have any such security module for key storage. The NSS database used by Firefox (and, on Linux, by Chrome) offers some of the same features, and does support password-based encryption of the entire database, but the browsers in question either don't use this feature at all, or use it with an automatically-supplied password that is known to the process (meaning it can't really be secret) and shared for all keys. The tool for accessing the database (`certutil`) also has support for hardware or software "tokens" (cryptographic modules, which can be third-party implementations rather than its own database), which can also have passwords. Finally, there does seem to be support for setting a password when importing a private key (typically paired with a certificate) using the [`pk12util` program](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/security/nss/legacy/tools/pk12util/index.html) but I think that might only be for the database (or at least its private key storage "slot") and thus the same DB-or-token level password rather than for the individual keys.

Comment: Thank you for your long explanation. I know some parts from your answer, but as I said before, I was really surprised when I copy my digital certificate from my Windows computer. I can imagine malicious websites/scripts can use my certificate without my knowledge.

Comment: Only if the site in question is vulnerable to CSRF, or has badly misconfigured CORS, which one would hope is not the case. It's a risk though.